# Terraform using count for both looping a variable and if statement to create the resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a resource that I only need to create depending on the value of a variable (if environment == "prod"),
The same resource is creating multiple folders on s3 also. takes another variable (list) and iterates through it to create the folder.

So these are the resources:

```
variable "s3_folders" {
  type        = list
  description = "The list of S3 folders to create"
  default     = ["ron", "al", "ted"]
}

resource "aws_s3_object" "smcupdater-folder-new-out" {
    count  = "${length(var.s3_folders)}"
    count      = var.environment == "prod" ? 1 : 0
    bucket = var.bucketname-smc-updater-upgrades
    acl    = "private"
    key    = "UpdaterActions/${var.s3_folders[count.index]}/NewActionsFiles/out-smcupdater/"
    source = "/dev/null"
    server_side_encryption = "AES256"
}
```

But I obviously can not use the count twice, I also tried with for each but this is also not allowed, Is there another way to do it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just update the ternary expression to do this:

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "smcupdater-folder-new-out" {
    count  = var.environment == "prod" ? length(var.s3_folders) : 0
    bucket = var.bucketname-smc-updater-upgrades
    acl    = "private"
    key    = "UpdaterActions/${var.s3_folders[count.index]}/NewActionsFiles/out-smcupdater/"
    source = "/dev/null"
    server_side_encryption = "AES256"
}
```

This way you are checking if the environment is `prod` and if so you are setting the `count` meta-argument to the length of the variable `s3_folders`.